# A confusion on the simplicity of the first eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry

I read that the first (non-zero) eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ is simple, that is, the corresponding eigenspace is one-dimensional. I believe this depends on the maximum principle and the fact that if there were two eigenfunctions corresponding to $\lambda_1$, then one could produce two nodal domains for each eigenfunction, which would violate Courant's nodal domain theorem. See also the following MO [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97490/first-eigenvalue-of-schr%C3%B6dinger-operator-is-simple?rq=1).

However, on the circle $S^1$, parametrized by $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ with the endpoints identified, $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are both eigenfunctions for the first eigenvalue, and each has two nodal domains. Is this a one-dimensional phenomenon, or have I misunderstood something regarding the simplicity of the first eigenvalue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about this, but a Schrödinger operator is of the form $-\Delta + V$, usually $V$ bounded from below or just $≥0$. It does not seem strange to me that the case $V=0$ will result in degenerate behaviour, in particular since the classical mechanics associated to this potential is super boring.

Comment: For $S^1$: What about eigenvalue $0$ corresponding to the constant function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the statement you're quoting. What's true is that for a compact Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, the lowest eigenvalue of the Laplacian (with Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions if the boundary is nonempty) is simple. *Not* the lowest nonzero eigenvalue.

In the case of a compact manifold with nonempty boundary, the lowest Dirichlet eigenvalue is positive and simple, while the lowest Neumann eigenvalue is zero and simple (with only the constants as eigenfunctions). For a compact manifold without boundary, the lowest eigenvalue is zero, again with only the constants as eigenfunctions.